# Tensorflow 'trainable=False' is ignored

Tags: tensorflow

I want to pass a fixed weight matrix to a 2D convolution operation in tensorflow. I tried putting `trainable=False` as follows but TF seems to ignore the option.

```py
w = tf.Variable(w, trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32, name='upscaleW')
data = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(data, w, outshapeF, strides, padding="SAME", data_format=data_format, name='UpsamplingDeconv2D')
```

It is constantly losing precision during training. The 1's become 0.98 then 0.96 etc and the 0's become 0.012 etc.

If I do `tf.trainable_variables()` the `upscaleW` are not there. I can only find them in `tf.global_variables()`, so they are not even in the list of trainable variables. I can't figure out how to freeze the weights.

Possibly this line is at fault? 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1075

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind. My bad. In my code I was passing to `minimize(var_list=tf.contrib.framework.get_variables())` instead of `get_trainable_variables` which obviously overrides the `trainable=False` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `trainable=False` keeps the variable out of the `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection in the graph, so they won't be trained when back-propagating.

It should work. No recent bugs.